# Need help understanding this odd Jest behavior

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I built a button for a React component library. To test the component, I used `jest@26`, `ts-jest@26`, `@types/jest@26`, `@testing-library/react@12.1.2`, and `@testing-library/jest-dom@5.14.1`.

While running the test, it threw an error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forwardRef' of undefined`. This error pointed to the following line in my button component code:

```js
export const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(...)
```

I ended up resolving this error by explicitly importing `forwardRef` in my import statement and replacing `React.forwardRef` with it:

```js
// this works for some reason in jest
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

export const Button = forwardRef(...)
```

This issue also applied to other aspects of my component code where I'm referencing attributes from `PropTypes` and resolving the error required me to explicitly import and reference those attributes.

```js
// before (throws error in jest)
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Button.propTypes = {
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf([...]),
  size: PropTypes.oneOf([...]),
  isFullWidth: PropTypes.bool,
}

// after (passes in jest)
import { oneOf, bool } from 'prop-types';

Button.propTypes = {
  variant: oneOf([...]),
  size: oneOf([...]),
  isFullWidth: bool,
}
```

Despite the changes making my tests pass, I find it odd that I have to make these changes for Jest, because my former code works in the browser. I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue and can explain this odd behavior.

Comment: it's hard to say. Can you print `React` variable to check what it is?

Comment: @slideshowp2 It's `undefined`.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr, were you able to resolve this issue? I am stumbling upon the same!

Comment: @JPS unfortunately not, but my guess is it's probably something to do with jest config

Answer (score 2):

In you `tsconfig.json` (or the tsconfig file you are using for Jest), turn on `esModuleInterop` flag

```json
{
   compilerOptions: {
...
      esModuleInterop: true,
...
   }
}
```

This help do what `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` is supposed to do in normal Typescript app.

What `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` does is to allow default import to be equivalent to namespace import of a module.

The deprecate of `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` is mentioned here: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/632